# Why doesn't this JavaScript variable get set to true?

Tags: javascript

In my code, the following condition returns `true` value:

```
($("#planSelected").val() == "PremiumPrepurchase")
```

But when I'm saving that value to a variable say 'isPremiumPrepurchase', the value of 'isPremiumPrepurchase' is getting false, Why this happening?

```
var isPremiumPrepurchase = ($("#planSelected").val() == "PremiumPrepurchase");
```

Thank you :)

Comment: 1) You should use === instead of ==
2) My guess is that when you run the code, the .val() isn't set yet.  But when you look at it through web tools, the code has executed and a .val() is set.

Comment: Do you wait 'till the document is ready?

Comment: this works. check here https://jsfiddle.net/ab3ta7oc/

Comment: @VtoCorleone - `===` vs `==` when comparing at least one non-empty string is irrelevant

Comment: @JaromandaX I think that was just general advise.

Comment: and my general advice was to stop worrying about == vs === where it is irrelevant

Comment: Andrew L you got it - put this as an answer and I'll mark it correct

Comment: @Izzy: Rather vote to close it as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572

Comment: @JaromandaX: Admittedly it is not trivial to know when exactly it is irrelevant (the rule isn't really "at least one non-empty string"), so beginners are definitely better off with generic advice.

Comment: @Bergi - yeah I made up the "rule" :p